# npm ERR! code E401 when trying to install fontawesome

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I keep getting this error when trying to install fontawesome using the command; `npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome`
FontAwesome link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
`[npm i free-solid-svg-icons]`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYM68.png)

I have already try to delete my packaje-lock.json file btw
I need a fix or do i have to to update my node.js?

Comment: Have you tried running `npm login` ?

Comment: yes i have, even got token to log in still same error